# PL SQL 'IF or CASE' using variable date

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am stuck with this and could use advice/help:

Basically, trying to set the date as a variable and then run select statements, using that date variable in the 'WHERE' section of the query. Not sure if I should be using IF or CASE, or neither? If its monday, i want to run 1 set of dates (prev thur and fri) any other day (just sysdate-2 and sysdate-1) Any help is much appreciated!

Code is below:

```
DECLARE
today_date number;
start_date date;
end_date date;

BEGIN
today_date := to_char(sysdate, 'D');
start_date := case when today_date ='2' then 'sysdate-4' else 'sysdate-2' 
end;
end_date := case when today_date ='2' then 'sysdate-3' else 'sysdate-1' end;

SELECT COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C, COLUMN D
FROM /*csv*/REPORT_NAME
WHERE COLUMN B between trunc(start_date)+21/24 and trunc(end_date)+21/24 and 
BOOK_NAME = 'xxxxxx' and SERVER = 'xxxxxx' and EX_ACTION = 'xxxxx';

end;
```

Comment: `sysdate` is a function. You need to remove the quotes enclosing `sysdate` expressions.

Comment: What do you want to do with the results of the query? Do you really want to be using PL/SQL at all?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing variables/functions and strings.  This should work.

```
DECLARE
today_date number;
start_date date;
end_date date;

BEGIN
today_date := to_char(sysdate, 'D');
start_date := case when today_date ='2' then sysdate-4 else sysdate-2 
end;
end_date := case when today_date ='2' then sysdate-3 else sysdate-1 end;

/* this won't work without declaring a cursor, and returning it to the client
SELECT COLUMN A, COLUMN B, COLUMN C, COLUMN D
FROM REPORT_NAME
WHERE COLUMN B between trunc(start_date)+21/24 and trunc(end_date)+21/24 and 
BOOK_NAME = 'xxxxxx' and SERVER = 'xxxxxx' and EX_ACTION = 'xxxxx';
*/
end;
```

Note you also have some implicit type conversion happening.  `today_date` should probably be `char(1)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  Where I keep getting errors is: 'PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement'.. It seems I am having issues using a select statement that is dependent on a IF or CASE (or vice versa)

Comment: Oh, right.  You have to return a cursor object, and your client needs to read the results from the cursor.  MySQL, SQL Server, and Sybase handle that differently...

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need variables for this, and you don't need PL/SQL; you can calculate the dates as part of the where clause using case expressions in that instead:

```
SELECT /*csv*/ COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D
FROM REPORT_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_B >= trunc(sysdate) - case to_char(sysdate, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
                    when 'Mon' then 4 else 2 end + 21/24
  AND COLUMN_B <  trunc(sysdate) - case to_char(sysdate, 'Dy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
                    when 'Mon' then 3 else 1 end + 21/24
  AND BOOK_NAME = 'xxxxxx'
  AND SERVER = 'xxxxxx'
  AND EX_ACTION = 'xxxxx';
```

I've taken the liberty of changing the logic from being based on the day number being 2 to it having a specific day abbreviation, because the value `D` returns is based on your NLS settings so it could vary (and give unexpected results) for someone else running your code. As day names and abbreviations are also NLS-dependent I've specified the language to use. (You can't specify how `D` is used in the same way, unfortunately).

I've changed the time window slightly, so it goes from 9pm on one day to *up to* but not including 9pm the next day. If you use `between` then it's inclusive at both ends, so runs on consecutive days you both pick up any data at exactly 21:00:00 from the overlapping day. That probably isn't what you want (but if it really is, just change `<` to `<=`, or revert to between if you prefer...).

If you want a PL/SQL wrapper you can do the same thing, but you either have to select the results *into* something like a collection, or use a ref cursor to return the result set to the caller. It isn't clear if you actually need or want to do that though.

Comment: Thanks so much, Alex!  Maybe ill just go this route!  Appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried selecting into your variables?

```
DECLARE
   TODAY_DATE   NUMBER;
   START_DATE   DATE;
   END_DATE     DATE;
BEGIN
   TODAY_DATE := TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'D');

   SELECT CASE WHEN TODAY_DATE = '2' THEN SYSDATE - 4 ELSE SYSDATE - 2 END,
          CASE WHEN TODAY_DATE = '2' THEN SYSDATE - 3 ELSE SYSDATE - 1 END
   INTO START_DATE, END_DATE
   FROM DUAL;

   SELECT COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D
   FROM REPORT_NAME /*csv*/
   WHERE     COLUMN_B BETWEEN TRUNC (START_DATE) + 21 / 24
                          AND TRUNC (END_DATE) + 21 / 24
         AND BOOK_NAME = 'xxxxxx'
         AND SERVER = 'xxxxxx'
         AND EX_ACTION = 'xxxxx';
END;
```